# How to add specific code for all user profile urls - rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-tags

I am trying to sort out metatags for my rails app. I have successfully added tags for each of my main pages.

There are lots of 'user' pages (i.e. each user's profile page) and 'tags' pages (i.e. each tag from the blog posts has its own page).

I want to add specific code (basically to NOINDEX it) that will apply to all 'user' pages, or all 'tags' pages.

I can't work out where to put the code or how to write it. Essentially I would like to be able to apply a line of code to all urls that are websitename.com/users/..... and websitename.com/tags/.... e.g.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do that in the layout or the view itself.

The layout would be conditionally set, like this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<% if controller_name == "users" && action_name == "show" %>
   <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
<% end %>
```

--

For the view, you could set a [`yield`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) block in your `layout`, and populate it with your view:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= yield :robots %>

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% content_for :robots do %>
   <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
<% end %>
```